# Conditionally break text list into two columns

Tags: css

I have a json file, which has few objects, this objects have an array of strings. sometimes this arrays can get to about 10 (or a little more) items.
when I have more than, let's say 5 items, when rendering the list to the screen, I want to break the list to two columns, with 5 items in each.

For example, I have a component, that has an image and to it's side I have the list of items from the array.

I have two of this component in one row, it looks like that:

```
COMPONENT 1      COMPONENT 2

IMAGE item1      IMAGE item1
      item2            item2
      item3            item3
      item4            item4
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       item10
```

I want to break `component 2` items into two column, so it will look like that:

```
COMPONENT 1      COMPONENT 2

IMAGE item1      IMAGE item1   item6
      item2            item2   .
      item3            item3   .
      item4            item4   .
                       item5   item10
```

So the items would be pretty much even in height.

I'm using css flex box, but I couldn't find a way to do so, with or without flex box.
I tried setting `max-height` but that also didn't work.

This is how I render the list of items:

```
    <div
      id="technologies"
      v-for="(technology, index) in technologies"
      :key="index"
    >
      <p>
        <span>#</span>
        <span style="color: #6e8898;">{{ technology }}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using CSS `columns`?

Comment: @connexo Thanks, but if I set css columns to two, it will also have two columns where I want only one column.

Comment: Then compare the number of items and conditionaly set e.g. `columns-2` as a CSS class.

Comment: @connexo Thank you, I am trying this now too, Florin G answer is working great, but I also want to try your solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like `flex-flow: column wrap`;
Here is an example:

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JohnDoah No problem, just keep in mind that Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the `flex-flow` property.